# How to overcome "no match for operator" error inside a method in a C++ class?

Tags: c++

I'm all new to C++ but I'm using it currently for my master thesis. I have a large code and I have a class inside which I declared a variable `Pbh` inside the private access specifier as follows

```
private:
std::vector<Scalar> Pbh;
```

Then I'm trying to update this variable inside a method inside this class as follows

```
template<class ElementVolumeVariables>

    void pointSource(PointSource& source,

                     const Element &element,

                     const FVElementGeometry& fvGeometry,

                     const ElementVolumeVariables& elemVolVars,

                     const SubControlVolume &scv) const

    {

        const auto& pos = source.position();

        const auto& volVars = elemVolVars[scv];



        if (pos[0] < 40.0) // injection

        {

          const Scalar volumeSource = 1.54e-3; // injectionRate is positive and m^3/s

          const Scalar massSource = volumeSource*IapwsH2O::liquidDensity(293, 17.0e5);

          const Scalar energySource = massSource*IapwsH2O::liquidEnthalpy(293, 17.0e5);

          source = NumEqVector({ massSource, energySource });
          
             if (pos[2] < 20.0) // Peaceman's Well Model
              {
          
              using std::log;
          
              const Scalar Pw = volVars.pressure(0);
           
              const Scalar wellRadius = 0.50 * 0.3048; 
           
              const Scalar gridHeight_ = 2.5; // meters
            
              const Scalar effectiveRadius_ = 0.208 * gridHeight_;  //Peaceman's Well Model
              
              const Scalar wellConstant = (2*3.1415*10e-13*gridHeight_)/(log(effectiveRadius_/wellRadius)); // Aquifer permability = 10e-13 m^2
          
               Pbh[scv] = (massSource * volVars.viscosity(0)) / (volVars.density(0) * wellConstant) + Pw; 
              
               }   
           

        }

        else // production

        {

           const Scalar volumeSource = -1.54e-3; // productionRate is negative and m^3/s

           const Scalar massSource = volumeSource*volVars.density(0); // using current control volume's water density

           const Scalar energySource = massSource*volVars.enthalpy(0); // using current control volume's water enthalpy

           source = NumEqVector({ massSource, energySource });

        }
        
      
      

    }
```

You can see that I'm trying to update the variable inside the nested if in the above code snippet

```
 if (pos[2] < 20.0) { }
```

Then I'm using another method in the same class to get the updated variable as follows

```
//! Get the flowing bottom hole pressure
     const std::vector<Scalar>& getPbh()
    {
        return Pbh;
    }
```

and of course I'm using an object of this class in main function to call the `getPbh()` method

Now, the error I'm getting whenever I try to compile the code is as follows:

error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const std::vector’ and ‘const SubControlVolume’
310 |                Pbh[scv] = (massSource * volVars.viscosity(0)) / (volVars.density(0) * wellConstant) + Pw;
|                ~~~^

I got confused and I even tried writing

```
Pbh = (massSource * volVars.viscosity(0)) / (volVars.density(0) * wellConstant) + Pw;
```

but it's not working and I'm getting this error:

error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const std::vector’ and ‘Dumux::OnePNIProblemDumux::Properties::TTag::OnePNICCMpfa::Scalar’ {aka ‘double’})
310 |                Pbh = (massSource * volVars.viscosity(0)) / (volVars.density(0) * wellConstant) + Pw;
|                ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Please note that the function `pointSource()` is overridden from another class so I cannot remove the `const`

I have no clue about the problem because I'm an absolute beginner with C++ and I just learnt about some basics. Could you help me solve this issue please ? I'm trying to get this variable `Pbh` but I cannot. Thanks in advance !

Comment: `vector`s can only be indexed using integer values, meanwhile you attempt to index it with `SubControlVolume`. The answer to your question depends on what exactly that is. Also, if you manage to sort that out, you still run into the problem that your method is declared non-modifying (the `const` keyword right between `)` and `{`), which means you are not allowed to modify the `Pbh` vector inside the object

Answer (score 0):

The function '**pointSource**' you have defined has been marked as '**const**'. You are guaranteeing that this function will not modify the internals of your object, yet you are trying to update the member variable '**Pbh**'.

By removing the '**const**' keyword, you will allow side-effects on your object & the error should go away.

---

The clue was in the :

```
‘const std::vector’
```

of :

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const std::vector’ and ‘const SubControlVolume’ 310 | Pbh[scv] = (massSource * volVars.viscosity(0)) / (volVars.density(0) * wellConstant) + Pw;
```

Comment: While this is true, the error message shows the error to be directly on the `operator[]`, indicating that `scv` is not a valid index (`operand types are ‘const std::vector’ and ‘const SubControlVolume’`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this function 'pointSource' is overloaded from another class so I cannot really modify it so how can I get the variable 'Pbh' ?! I will re-edit the question to add this information.

Comment: You are correct - as per your initial comment, without knowing what 'SubControlVolume' is, we cannot rule it out of errors with it also.

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes Your discussion was useful I realized I should set the type of variable 'Pbh' to double instead of std::vector<Scalar>  but as you both mentioned the 'const' keyword does not allow me to modify the variable 'Pbh' and  at the same time the function is overloaded from another class so I cannot remove that 'const' keyword, otherwise I get an error. Is there a workaround to get this variable ?!

Comment: @MahmoudAboElSeoud Do you mean overloaded, or overridden? If it's the latter, the base class seems to be actually not expecting you to modify the object, so you should not do that unless absolutely necessary. If you really need to modify it still, [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) should do the trick

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes yes it's overridden....thank you...I think you're totally right !

Comment: While @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes last-ditch suggestion to use 'const_cast' would "do the trick", I strongly advise you question what the function is supposed to do. If the const-ness cannot be enforced, perhaps it should become a entirely new non-const function. The 'const' keyword is there for the compiler to give you a gentle slap on the wrist when you try to introduce side-effects & are not supposed to; 'const_cast' is willingly shooting yourself in the foot. Think of 'const_cast' as a last-resort workaround when interfacing with problematic/opaque external/third party APIs.